# How to automatically find link of download button and download corresponding file with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, url, download, python-requests

I have permission to download some weather data from the following website:

https://www.meteobridel.com/messnetz/index3.php#

I was wondering is there is a possibility to automatically find the download URL behind the 'CSV' button and then download that csv file with Python.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Safari()
url = 'https://meteobridel.lu/?page_id=5'
browser.get(url)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CSV"]').click()
browser.close()
```

Thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Safari()
url = 'https://meteobridel.lu/?page_id=5'
browser.get(url)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//body/div[@id='main']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[4]').click()
browser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the page you provided I can't find an "CSV"-ID.
Maybe try getting the button by class:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(r"//a[contains(@class, 'buttons-csv')]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

element is inside iframe so you have to switch to it first , as the id of frame is unique you can switch like

```
browser.switch_to.frame("iframe")

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"CSV")]/..').click()
```